# Implementation of coq command

Tags: coq

I am using destruct command in less or equal situation and same command in 
   less than condition. I have problem in applying (ltb_correct) command.Error 
   message is "this command is not found. Guide me how to apply ltb_correct. In 
   standard library leb_correct exist,but ltb_correct does not exist.

```
  `destruct (le_lt_dec n m).
   Lemma leb_correct m n : m <= n -> (m <=? n) = true.
  (leb_correct _ _ l).

  destruct (lt_dec  n m).
  Lemma ltb_correct m n : m < n -> (m <? n) = true.
  (ltb_correct _ _ l).`
```

Answer (score 2):

The fact that no `ltb_correct` equivalent exists in the standard library probably means that you should not use this lemma. If you search for lemmas involving `Nat.leb` and `Nat.ltb`, you will find the following ones:

```
Nat.leb_le : forall n m, (n <=? m) = true <-> n <= m
Nat.ltb_lt : forall n m, (n <?  m) = true <-> n <  m.
```

You can use such equivalences with the `apply` tactic:

```
Require Import Coq.Arith.Arith.

Goal forall n m : nat, False.
intros n m.
destruct (le_lt_dec n m) as [l|l].
- apply Nat.leb_le in l.
  admit.
- apply Nat.ltb_lt in l.
  admit.
Admitted.
```